# Working with multiple database instances in development

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

My project is an ASP.Net MVC Website that has been deployed to multiple customers, and each customer has their own SQL Server database. As you'd expect, the data in each database is different, so even in development we have separate databases for each customer. The database schemas are identical. We have a custom database context extending DbContext and managed by Unity.

Currently we switch between these databases by either renaming the databases themselves, or editing the connection strings in Web.config (technically in ConnectionStrings.private.config, which we pull into Web.config using a configSource attribute).

**How can I develop the same codebase against multiple customer databases at once, without editing any configuration when switching database?** For example, I might have one customer at http://customerone.localhost/ and another at http://customertwo.localhost/ (different port numbers would be OK too). Each accessing their own database but sharing the c# code.

In apache I can use `<If>` or `SetEnvIf` to set configuration based on the url, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in IIS. When I try to change it in c# code I am told it is read only.

To be clear I don't want any changes to be written back to web.config - I just want the custom database connection string to be used for the life of the request.

Comment: Are the schemas of each database identical? What RDMS are you using?

Comment: I've added that to the question. Answers are Yes, and SQL Server

Comment: You could use either a DI framework or enrich the constructor of your DbContext. Select a connection string in the `web.config` based on the request context or change the database name based on the request context. Personally I prefer the web.config route, one entry per database and select the named entry based on the request.